# Add Fragment to Backstack Failing

Tags: android, kotlin

In my fragment's `onCreate()` I want to add another fragment to the backstack so that when user presses back it will go there.

```
override fun onCreate(savedInstanceState: Bundle?) {
     super.onCreate(savedInstanceState)
     addFragmentOnTop()      
}

fun addFragmentOnTop() {
    activity?.supportFragmentManager
        ?.beginTransaction()
        ?.replace(R.id.container, MyFragment())
        ?.addToBackStack(null)
        ?.commit()
}
```

When I make the call it crashes with this error:

> java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: No view found for id 0x7f0b00c9

Comment: https://medium.com/@bherbst/managing-the-fragment-back-stack-373e87e4ff62 hope this works for you.

Comment: @daniel.jbatiz I did that and it fails with a crash.

Comment: The fragments must be added in order. You don't insert in a stack. The exception might have something to do with the fact that MyFragment's layout is not found, or that R.id.container does not exist.

Comment: Ok so the ID was wrong. However, it is adding the fragment to the current fragment. Not on the backstack. Both are visible

Comment: addToBackStack(null) cannot pasa null ; you got to pass the current fragment to the BackStack

Answer (score -1):

You can use Activity's supportFragmentManager instead of FragmentManager like
"**activity?.supportFragmentManager**"

If you need listen onBackPress in fragment.

```
 activity?.onBackPressedDispatcher?.addCallback(object : OnBackPressedCallback(true) {
    override fun handleOnBackPressed() {

    }
 })
```